# Cartoon where the main characters, two boys and a girl, could turn into a mantis, a hummingbird and a chameleon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was not a series, but a single cartoon.

If I'm not mistaken there was one of the Egyptian gods. Two boys and a girl traveled with a small chameleon, a praying mantis and a hummingbird. Children and animals (let's call them talismans) could interact with each other and transform into superheroes, but the girl could not turn into a hummingbird, because the hummingbird was injured during the fight with a scorpion (one of the talisman/animal of their enemies).

So these two boys and girl were fighting against another two boys and a girl; one of the boys was a brother of the girl and she couldn’t talk, like she was voiceless.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Do you recall the animation style or anything distinctive about the characters?

Comment: My first thought, when seeing a reference to transforming to a chameleon was [Combo Ninos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_Ni%C3%B1os), but it's South American gods and talismans, and they transform into a tiger, a bull, an eagle, and an iguana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this ***[Guardians of the Lost Code 3D](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1632477/)*** (2010)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code):

> *Guardians of the Lost Code* (Spanish: *Brijes 3D*) is a 2010 animated adventure film, created by Ricardo González Duprat, distributed by Videocine.

> During a field trip to the history museum, the students Freddy, Atzi, and Kimo discover a giant stone disk called the Codex in the storage room they are exploring. Three of the brije within it, the deities Quetzalcoatl, Ra and Chu Jung, emerge and reveal to them that they are the three people chosen to restore the ancestral alliance between humans and brijes, an alliance that was fractured with the emergence of science and technology.
>
> The brijes are magical animal spirits that have been in contact with human beings since the beginning of time. Every human had a brije; the human cared for his brije and vice versa. When the human turned 13, a human shaman taught both partners a bonding technique that allowed them to synchronize and transform into a warrior form, gaining extraordinary power allowing them to perform various acts of heroism. Unfortunately, with the birth of modern science and technology, this union was slowly severed as humans stopped believing in magic, leading to tragic results. The brije in the Codex created and sealed themselves within it to protect the knowledge of the warrior form bonding technique from the forces of darkness that seek it.

It's an animated movie about three kids who wander into a storeroom in a history museum and find an ancient stone disc, through which they come into contact with brijes, supernatural creatures they can 'synchronise' with to assume monstrous "warrior forms."

The protagonists are a boy named Freddy, another boy named Kimo, and a girl named Atzi; they're paired with brijes resembling a grasshopper, a chameleon, and a hummingbird, respectively.

The main antagonist is a wealthy, middle-aged man named [Elmer](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Elmer_(Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code)) who recruits three kids to work for him; a boy named [Spikes](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Spikes_(Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code)), a girl named [Muty](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Muty), and another boy named Zejas. Zejas is paired with a brije resembling a scorpion, whilst Muty is Spikes' sister, and doesn't speak due to trauma.

> Prior to the events of *Guardians of the Lost Code,* Muty encountered a gang of teenagers who brutally beat her when she was just nine years old, she screamed for help but no one came to her aid, thus leaving her to be the plaything for the gang. This caused her to lose the will and ability to speak (Hence her nickname) and drove Muty and her brother Spikes to resent the world, believing everyone was coward and greedy.

The hummingbird brije is injured by the 'scorpion' brije at one point, and consequently, Atzi doesn't assume her warrior until the climax of the film.

You can view the scene where the hummingbird brije is injured by the 'scorpion' brije at around the 59:34 mark in the video below.

Comment: oh my god, yes! I've been looking for this cartoon for  five years! thank you so much for the help!